# How can I make a BottomAppBar stick to top of keyboard? flutter

Tags: flutter

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(

        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: TextField(
            maxLines: 1,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Tags', border: InputBorder.none),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
```

Although the TextField for contents sticks to keyboard(Theres a TextField for contents in the body.), the BottomAppBar doesnt do.

I chose to use BottomAppbar to put a TextField on the bottom. Is it a bad way to do it?

[idle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81CfD.png)

[when I cursor on the tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97wrE.png)

Comment: Is it possible to add expected output screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a `TextField` in the bottom navigation bar, it is not thought to hold such elements.

What I would do instead is something like (:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Colum(
        children: [
          // Your widgets
          ...
          Spacer(),
          TextField(
             ...
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here, `Spacer` will push the `TextField` to the bottom of the application. If you did not use a `SingleChildScrollView`, you would get an overflow error since the keyboard would overlap the `TextField`. However, with the `SingleChildScrollView` the content will be made scrollable so there's no overlap.

Comment: thanks. tried it, but studio throws 'RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded'. Should I wrap the TextField with another widget?